# Maximal integer value for double

Tags: java, double

That is the maximal integer value could be assigned to Java `double` and still behave as an integer value? I mean, it sill must satisfy the usual conditions

```
a + 1 > a;
a - 1 < a;
```

With the values big enough, even `a + 1000` may still be `a` due rounding errors.

I need to use `double` as a counter and want to know where is the upper limit of the reliable counting.

Comment: Why use a double rather than a long? Or even a BigInteger if you really need huge values?

Comment: another solution is to use a arbitrary precision arithmetic library like http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/

Comment: Why not write a program and see? It's not hard to loop and test, a 5 line Java program.

Comment: You can not add 1 to the maximum value and get a meaningful value.  MAX_VALUE + 1 = undefined.

Comment: This question is about Java double, not C double. And the size of C double is implementation specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number that you're looking for is `9,007,199,254,740,991` because `9,007,199,254,740,991 + 1 = 9,007,199,254,740,992` but `9,007,199,254,740,992 + 1 = 9,007,199,254,740,992`.

I found this experimentally using the following snippet.

```
double a = 9.007199254E15;
while (a + 1 > a) {
    a += 1;
}
System.out.println(a);
```

Given the fact that you are using this value as a counter, and that the maximum value for longs is `2^63 - 1 = 9.22E18` (as Peter pointed out), there seems to be no reason not to use longs instead.

Comment: Might be clearer to write 9,007,199,254,740,992 (or 9 007 199 254 740 992 depending on your country).

Comment: the theory supports this too: a double has a precision of approximately 16 decimal digits (~15.955). int has a maximum of 10 decimal digits, therefore +1 will always change the value as long as you are within the 32bit integer range. for a 64bit integer that changes at the stated value (long has a maximum of 19 decimal digits)

Comment: The mantissa in a double is 53 bits, which is why the maximum value is 2^53.

Comment: I have tried this code as well and confirm. 9.007199254740992E15.

Comment: It can be true but you can't talk for sure based only on that test. You can't prove that a+1>a for every int smaller that that. To do so, you'd have to analyse the representation of double in JRE and prove it mathematically.

Answer (score 4):

> I need to use double as a counter and want to know where is the upper limit of the reliable counting.

I can't imagine why you would use a `double` as a counter to store an integer, but the limit is in the range of eight million billion (2^53).  If you use a `long` as a counter the limit is 9 billion billion.

Comment: Looks like the limit is exactly 2^53! How did you find that value?

Comment: @wheels - See [Wikipedia on "Machine epsilon"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)

Comment: @wheels 2^53-1 is the largest number where all the bits fit into the mantissa and 2^53 also work because it is a power of two and the mantissa is all zeros, one more and the mantissa can't store the value accurately.

Answer (score 1):

If, by integer, you mean `int`, then all possible `int` values fit into a `double` since int is defined to be a 32-bit signed integer quantity, and a `double` has a mantissa size of 53 bits (into which an `int` value fits comfortably). If you mean `long`, on the other hand, then things are different, since `long`s are 64-bit signed integer quantities.

The maximum long value representable should be something like 2<sup>53</sup> - 1 or so (didn't try it, so may be wrong).